# What exists in the .ssh directory when you create it?

Tags: ssh, terminal, ssh-keys

I'm working on setting up an SSH key on a VM. I needed to create a `.ssh` directory  at the root: `mkdir .ssh`. Right away, the directory has contents:

`drwxr-xr-x.  2 myusername folder    6 Jun 20 19:51 .
drwxr-xr-x. 15 myusername folder 4096 Jun 20 19:51 ..`

Just for learning purposes, what are the contents of the `.ssh` directory I just made?

Comment: This is not a programming question. IT should go to [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None - `.` points to the current directory and `..` points to the upper directory.